# I am using jquery's toggleClass method on a click event to an li , refreshing the page, the class is already applied without clicking on the li

Tags: javascript

Below is the JS and the html, I tried using the preventDefault method but to no avail.

```
$(this).parent().remove();
event.stopPropagation();
});

$("li").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).removeClass("done");
    $(this).toggleClass("done");
});

  <ul>
                <li class="done"> <span class="deleteButton">X</span> sdfd</li>
                <li class="done"> <span class="deleteButton">X</span> sdf</li>
                <li class="done"> <span class="deleteButton">X</span> sdfds</li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: Hey, Can you provide a working snippet ?

Comment: you have already provided the class on li and in jquery you are first removinf it and then adding it by toggling. What exact behaviour you want. initially done class should be there or not

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that you're applying the class within the HTML markup and not removing it on load. If you don't add the class to begin with this will fix your issue. Working example can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tzq6a2go/1/).

```
<ul>
  <li> <span class="deleteButton">X</span> sdfd</li>
  <li> <span class="deleteButton">X</span> sdf</li>
  <li> <span class="deleteButton">X</span> sdfds</li>
</ul>
```

```
$("li").click(function(event){
    $(this).toggleClass("done");
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Matt, just removed the class from the html, and it's working :)

Comment: @SiddharthLodha no problem. If you would be kind enough to set this as the accepted answer then that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if this helps

```css
.done {
color:yellow;
font-size:20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("li").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass("done");
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
                <li > <span class="deleteButton">X</span> sdfd</li>
                <li > <span class="deleteButton">X</span> sdf</li>
                <li > <span class="deleteButton">X</span> sdfds</li>
            </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have already added the class to the elements. You should declare the class and then you should assign the class when the click-on the element. this what you can do.

```js
$("li").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("done");
});
```

```css
.done{
    font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
</ul>
```